# Zend pagination with limited number of links and dots between

Tags: zend-framework, pagination, zend-paginator

I have implemented a Zend Pagination but can't figure out how to limit the number of links in the pagination. I know about setPageRange, but it isn't exactly what i want.

Currently the pagination looks like this.

```
< | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | >
```

But what i want is something like this:

for page 1

```
< | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 14 | 15 | 16 | >
```

for page 8

```
< | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 7 | 8 | 9 | ... | 14 | 15 | 16 | >
```

for page 14

```
< | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i can give you pagination helper script which i have implemented in one of my application and it is same like as above you want.

```
<?php

 if ($this->pageCount) :
 $midRange = floor(sizeof($this->pagesInRange) / 2);
 if (($this->current + $midRange) < $this->pageCount && $this->pageCount > 5) : 
    array_pop($this->pagesInRange); 
 $display_end = true;
 endif; 

 ?>
<div class="paginationControl<?php echo  $this->position; ?>">

 <div class="paginationControl_pages">
 <!-- Previous page link -->

 <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
 <?php if($this->extraVar != "" ){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo  $this->url(array_merge($this->extraVar,array('page' => $this->previous))). $this->query; ?>" class="paging-active">&nbsp;Previous&nbsp;</a> &nbsp;
 <?php }else {?>
            <a href="<?php echo  $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)). $this->query; ?>" class="paging-active">&nbsp;Previous&nbsp;</a> &nbsp;
 <?php }?>
 <?php else: ?>
 <span class="paging-active"><strong>&nbsp;Previous&nbsp;</strong></span>&nbsp;
 <?php endif; ?>
 <span ><?php if (($this->current - $midRange) > $this->first && $this->pageCount > 5): ?></span>
 <?php  
 array_shift($this->pagesInRange);?>

 <?php if($this->extraVar != "" ){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($this->extraVar,array('page' => $this->first))) . $this->query; ?>" ><span class="paging"><?php echo $this->first ?></span></a>...
 <?php } else {?> 
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->first)) . $this->query; ?>" ><span class="paging"><?php echo $this->first ?></span></a>...
 <?php }?>

 <?php endif; ?>
 <!-- Numbered page links -->
 <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>

 <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>

 <?php if($this->extraVar != "" ){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($this->extraVar,array('page'=>$page))); ?>""><span class="paging"><?php echo $page; ?></span></a>
        <?php }else{ ?>  
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page'=>$page)); ?>"><span class="paging"><?php echo $page; ?></span></a>
        <?php } ?>

 <?php else: ?>

        <span class="paging-active"><strong><?php echo $page; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php if (!empty($display_end)) : 
 ?>
 <?php if($this->extraVar != "" ){ ?>
 ...<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($this->extraVar,array('page' => $this->last))) . $this->query; ?>" ><span class="paging"><?php echo $this->last ?></span></a> 
 <?php }else{?>
 ...<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->last)) . $this->query; ?>" ><span class="paging"><?php echo $this->last ?></span></a> 
 <?php }?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <!-- Next page link -->
 <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
  <?php if($this->extraVar != "" ){ ?>
  &nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($this->extraVar,array('page' => $this->next))) . $this->query; ?>" class="paging-active">&nbsp;Next&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;
  <?php }else{?>
 &nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)) . $this->query; ?>" class="paging-active">&nbsp;Next&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;
 <?php }?>
 <?php else: ?>
 &nbsp;<span class="paging-active"><strong>Next&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></span>&nbsp;
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

hope this will sure help you to get your desire OUTPUT.

Comment: @Tudor Ravoiu, glad to help you. pls vote up so some one can trust our answer and use in future.

Answer (score 0):

Using this will produce the desired output.
For example with last number as 20, first number as 1, current with 8, and limit with 3 links will produce output

first,1,..,7,8,9,..,20,last

```
    <?php

    $last=20;
    $current=8;
    $first=1;
    $output="";
    $show_limit=3;


    if($show_limit==$last){
        for($i=1;$i<=$last;$i++){
            if(empty($output))
                $output.="$i";
            else
                $output.=",$i";
        }
        $output="first,$output,last";
    }else{
        if($current-ceil($show_limit/2) <=$first){
            for($i=1;$i<=$show_limit+1;$i++){
                $output.=",$i";
            }
            $output="first$output,..,$last,last";
        }else if($current+ceil($show_limit/2)>=$last){
           for($i=1;$i<$show_limit+1;$i++){
                $output=",". intval($last-$i). $output;
            }
            $output="first,1,..".$output. ",$last,last";
        }else{
            $output="first,1,..,";
            $start=$current-floor($show_limit/2);
            for($i=0;$i<$show_limit;$i++){
                $cursor=intval($start+$i);
                if($cursor==$last)
                    break;
                $output.=$cursor.",";
            }
            $output.="..,$last,last";
        }
    }


    echo $output."\n";
```