# How to hide some pagination numbers in between and keep the first 3 page numbers and last page number

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

The below php code results pagination as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , ...

I would like to get the result as 1, 2, 3, ... ,10

```
    if ( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var( 'paged' );
        echo '<ul class="page-numbers nav-pagination links text-center">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $page = str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-number', $page );
            echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We don’t want you to just tell us what you _want_, we also want to tell us what you have tried so far, in an attempt to achieve it. This site is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share an example.

[Adding dots between numbers of pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401962/adding-dots-between-numbers-of-pagination)

```
if ( is_array( $pages ) ) {

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var( 'paged' );

echo '<ul class="page-numbers nav-pagination links text-center">';

$i = '0';

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {

$page = str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-number', $page );

    $i++;

    if($i == 4){

        echo '...';

    } elseif($i < 4 || $i > (count($pages) -3)){

        echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';

    }

}

echo '</ul>';

}
```

I think it works fine.

Correction: You can fix $i == '4' and add "..." after the number you specified. Or you can find the median value of the $pages array and replace it with 4.

Comment: Dear Metin, Thanks, this is working but could you please modify it for "i == 4" ? how to display all page numbers before the current page and the "..." just start after the current page. Because with the current code, when we are at , let say. page 5, it doesnot display. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code I suppose that the `$pages` is an array containing the page numbers 1-10 and you want to get the first `n` and the last number listed.

There are several solutions for this depending on the use case.

### Solution 1

If the listing always starts at `1` and you can hard-code the first three elements and the ellipsis and only add the last page number to the list:

```php
$pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$n = 3;

for($k=1;$k<=$n;$k++) {
   echo "<li>$k</li>";
}
echo "<li>...</li><li>" . count($pages) . "</li>";
```

### Solution 2

If for some reason you have to iterate through the whole `$pages` array, then you can add an ellipsis after the n-th element and don't print for the rest but for the last one:

```php
$pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$n = 3;

foreach($pages as $page) {
    if($page <= $n || $page == count($pages))
        echo "<li>$page</li>";
    else if($page == $n+1) 
        echo "<li>...</li>";
    
    // something else for all pages
}
```

### Solution 3

You can also use some advanced indexing to get the first n elements plus the last one and run the loop only for those (this also works if the page numbers are not 1,2,3,...)

```php
$pages = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X'];
$n = 3;

foreach(array_merge(range(0, $n-1), [count($pages)-1]) as $idx) {
    echo "<li>$pages[$idx]</li>";
    
    if($idx == $n-1) {
        echo "<li>...</li>";
    }
   
}
```